# Mule API Proxy returns 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-api-manager

I installed a Mule API proxy on premise on a very restricted server.
In order to see if the proxy is working I tried the following from the server:

```
curl https://localhost:8080/console/
```

As expected, the proxy responded with some html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
...
<api-console-app  ...>
..
```

When trying to send a valid request:

```
 curl -Lv -X 'GET'  'https://localhost:8080/<basepath>/<some valid path>'   -H 'accept: application/json'
```

It returns http code 503:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: ...
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*     ...
> GET /...
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> accept: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2023 17:10:48 GMT
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

Worth to mention that if I change the base path I get an 404 - not found error instead, so I'm reaching the proxy.

I can't find the error in the Mule API log or in Anypoint platform (portal).

Any ideas? How can I record/access the log for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't setup the credentials so the API can connect to API Manager when executing. There is a security feature called [Gatekeeper](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-gateway/mule-gateway-gatekeeper) that prevents APIs not connecting to answer requests and instead returns 503 status. This is to prevent an API that is not receiving policies from API Manager from execute unsecured. You should either:

1. [Configure the credentials](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-gateway/mule-gateway-org-credentials-mule4) (recommended): depending if you are running on Anypoint Studio or deploying directly to CloudHub you have to set the right configurations to set client_id&client_secret.
2. Disable the Gatekeeper (not recommended): this should be only used when doing local tests. See the [Gatekeeper](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-gateway/mule-gateway-gatekeeper) documentation for details.

Additional references: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/API-returns-503-Service-Unavailable-error-to-clients

Comment: Yes I agree this is probably gatekeeper. Also make sure your on prem server is allowed through firewalls out to anypoint platform, and has a proper license file with hybrid core entitlements installed.

Comment: @aled, is the following error related? :
ERROR ...[agw-api-tracking-retry.01] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.gw.deployment.tracking.ApiTracker: Failed to retrieve API information for API '18903208'. This request will be retried after some backoff time. Reason: com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.gw.client.exception.HttpConnectionException: An error occurred executing OAuth HTTP Request. Reason: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <anypoint.mulesoft.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.cheqzone.com, *.adzouk1tag.com, *.combotag.com]

Comment: Found out the root cause. The machine is not getting dns updates and some of the Anypoint cloud IPs had changed. So, that is why the API is not connecting,and why i got this odd errors, yet I do some things like update the API using anypoint platform. This answer was more than half way. Thanks.